# Cannot deserialize value of type java.sql.Timestamp from String

Tags: java, spring-boot, timestamp

I have a bean class where I am setting the recReceived time using the below code. When I am executing the below code, I am getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
> deserialize value of type `java.sql.Timestamp` from String
> ............

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
TestBean TestBean = new TestBean();
TestBean.setRecReceived(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonData = gson.toJson(TestBean); // Cannot ignore this part as it is sent from first server to second server
Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonData, HashMap.class); //Received at server end
TestBean abc = (TestBean) convertMapToEntity(map, TestBean.class);
}
    
    // Cannot edit this function
    public static Object convertMapToEntity(Map<String, Object> object, Class<?> objClass) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(object, objClass);

    }
    
// Bean class - Cannot edit this file
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class TestBean {
    Timestamp recReceived;
    Timestamp responseSent;
    // getter and setter    
}
```

It will be really helpful if someone can help me let know what I am doing wrong in the code or can any change be done in code without touching the non editable function or file
Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, `java.sql.Timestamp` is one of the terrible legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Replaced specifically by `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type
> `java.sql.Timestamp` from String "Jun 15, 2022, 07:54:56 PM": not a
> valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jun 15, 2022,
> 07:54:56 PM': Cannot parse date "Jun 14, 2022, Jun 15, 2022, 07:54:56
> PM": not compatible with any of standard forms
> ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd
> MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

beacause your JSON is having the date format which is not compatible with standard date format that Jackson uses for deserializations.

Below are  standard formats for a date which Jackson supports:

yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss.SSS

EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz

yyyy-MM-dd

To fix this, you will use
`.setDateFormat()` method which configures Gson to serialize Date objects according to the pattern provided.

You will need to set one of above mentioned patterns which jackson support.

Here is the complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {


        TestBean TestBean = new TestBean();
        TestBean.setRecReceived(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        String jsonData = gson.toJson(TestBean); // Cannot ignore this part as it is sent from first server to second server
        Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonData, HashMap.class); //Received at server end
        TestBean abc = (TestBean) convertMapToEntity(map, com.example.demo.dto.TestBean.class);
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
```

If you run above code, you should see output like this:

```
TestBean{recReceived=2022-06-14 04:01:56.279, responseSent=null}
```